# @ and ? in android style layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i don't really understand the difference between the "?" and "@" in those examples :

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

and

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

both are searching in the android system, but what are the real differences? and is it possible to look at a dir-file to see the different possibilities? i tried to look in my "android" folder, but i can't find the path for those "attributes"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the string indicates that the XML parser should parse and expand the rest of the ID string and identify it as an ID resource.

and the question-mark (?) indicates that we're referencing a resource value in the currently loaded theme.

For detail description [check this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)